# How to vertically center align 3 divs at extreme left, extreme right and absolute centre in a wrapper div with dynamic dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I am new to Svelte and I absolutely love it, while designing the top-navigation bar for my project, I couldn't achieve the desired result because of Svelte's JS DOM Styling methods. Would be great if you guide me on this.

> The markup is as follows

```
 <div class="top-nav">
        <div class="width-restriction">
            <div id="hamburger-icon">
                <HamburgerIcon /> <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme left -->
            </div>
            <h1 class="head" id="logo">VKYD</h1> <!-- Logo; needs to be centered -->
            <div id="shopping-cart-icon">
                <ShoppingCartIcon /> <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme right -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far with css? You should post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `flexbox` on the `.width-restriction`:

```css
.width-restriction {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div class="width-restriction">
    <div id="hamburger-icon">
      icon-hamburger
      <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme left -->
    </div>
    <h1 class="head" id="logo">VKYD</h1>
    <!-- Logo; needs to be centered -->
    <div id="shopping-cart-icon">
      icon-shop
      <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme right -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Svelte, you need to define the styles in a `style` tag just like that:

```html
<style>
    .width-restriction {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>

 <div class="top-nav">
     <div class="width-restriction">
         <div id="hamburger-icon">
             icon-hamburger <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme left -->
         </div>
         <h1 class="head" id="logo">VKYD</h1> <!-- Logo; needs to be centered -->
         <div id="shopping-cart-icon">
             icon-shop <!-- Imported component, essentially an icon, doesn't affect styling; needs to be at the extreme right -->
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Check the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bcda408d2f9a46b4b76b028dc3a11299?version=3.26.0).

Comment: No problem ahah ;) please don't forget to validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Svelte but usually, that type of placement can be achieved quite easily using

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

You can check here for a quick demo of the property ( see bottom of the page): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Hope this can help you!